# Convert Ascii Numeric Value back to text in TCL

Tags: tcl, ascii

I have a variable from matlab that is defined as uint8 which gives ascii numerical value.

e.g. variable = `uint8('Hello World');`
in ascii = `72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100`

Is it possible to convert this back to a printable name in tcl i.e. back to "Hello World"?

Comment: I guess you need to define a string comprised of all the ASCII characters (at lest the ones you are interested in, blanking the others) and use your MatLab result to look up the characters there using `string index ALL_ASCII_STRING <char_code>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
% set var "72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100"
72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100
% binary format c* $var
Hello World
```

Comment: It's possible (with more complex variants) that `encoding convertfrom` will also be needed. It's not required for ASCII or ISO 8859-1.